# What is the difference between $var[1] and @var[1]?

Tags: perl

```
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my @var = (11, 22, 33);

# I think this is the TYPICAL use
say Dumper $var[1];  # output: 22
$var[1] = 88;
say Dumper $var[1];  # output: 88

# What's the difference?
say Dumper @var[1];  # output: 88
@var[1] = 99;
say Dumper @var[1];  # output: 99
```

For a long time, I thought if I want to access an item in an array, I can only use `$var[i]` (because every book writes it like this).

But, recently I found I can use `@var[i]` to access the item as well.

After some research, I found it seems like `@var[i]` is something called a slice.

What's the difference between `$var[1]` and `@var[1]`? If I only use `@var[i]` as a right value, is `@var[i]` and `$var[i]` the same?

Comment: Don use `@ary[0]`. You'll get a warning, too -- `Scalar value @ary[0] better written as $ary[0]`.  Now, `@ary[0..1]` is indeed a "slice"  -- it's a list of values, thus the `@`.  But with just one index it's a scalar. it'll accept the syntax but will warn.

Comment: fyi -- Edited my post ("answer") quite a bit since the original posting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the variable carries a single value it's a scalar and it needs a `$`. So strictly

```
$ary[0]
```

With the leading `$`, if there is an expression in `[]` it is evaluated in a scalar context.

If it's a multi-valued quantity then the variable starts with a `@` (or `%` for an associative array), like the mentioned [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices)

```
@ary[0,-1], @ary[2..5]
```

where in `[]` there need be an expression returning a list of integers.  The expression is evaluated in a list context.

With a single index the use of `@` is tolerated (it works) but it draws a warning

```
Scalar value @ary[0] better written as $ary[0]
```

Don't do that.  If an expression in `[]` at runtime happens to return a single value no warning is emitted with a leading `@`.  If the expression is intended to return a single value then again the quantity is clearly meant to be a scalar so use a leading `$`.

Now what the `Dumper` library does is `Dumper`'s design decision...

---

An exception is the new [postfix dereference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) syntax,

```
$arrayref->@*
$hashref->%*
```

where a term yielding a list starts with `$`.  See docs.  Traditionally we write this as

```
@{ $arrayref }
```

where the expression in `{}` needs to return an array reference.  In this case, with a simple scalar variable inside, one can also write

```
@$arrayref
```

See this [in perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut#Using-References) and [in perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Using-References).

Comment: The exceptions all have a `@` or `%` right after a `->`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `@var[...]` syntax is called a "slice". It nominally takes a list and extracts the elements of the array at the indices given by that list. Here's an example:

```
use strict;
my @test = qw/one two three four five/;
print join( ', ', @test[1..2] )."\n";
```

This gives:

```
two, three
```

In your case, you're passing a scalar, not a list, but perl will accept it anyhow. It will warn you about it, though:

```
use strict;
my @test = qw/one two three four five/;
print @test[1];
```

Output:

```
Scalar value @test[1] better written as $test[1] at so77095380.pl line 3.
two
```